# for-loops and if-else statement when assigning or rounding values to a variable in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

Trying to figure out how I can write code in R using for-loops and if-else statements. Basically I have been given the following variables:

```
> x = c(6, 1, 5, 10, 3, 0, 3, 7, 1, 6, 1, 4)

> y = NA
```

The code should round or what I think is really assigning any number that is 5 or greater to 10 and any number below 5 to 0.
So the outcome should basically be the variable y equaling a bunch of 0s and 10s.

I have tried a few codes with no luck:

```
>for (y in 1:12) {y = x 

>if (x > 5){printText = paste('10'[y])} 

>else if (x < 5){printText = paste('0'[y])}
}
```

Please help

Comment: What happens if `x == 5`?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that if a number is 5 or greater then it should be rounded to 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your statement you have two options: x >= 5 and x <5. You said anything at and above 5 should go to 10 and anything below 5 should go to 0. So, the following for loop with conditionals (if) statements will work.

Cheers,

```
x = c(6, 1, 5, 10, 3, 0, 3, 7, 1, 6, 1, 4)

y = c()

for(i in 1:length(x)){
  if(x[i] >= 5){
    y[i] = 10
  }else if(x[i] < 5){
    y[i] = 0
  }
}

#y = 10  0 10 10  0  0  0 10  0 10  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe this is what I am looking for.

Comment: Happy to help. Hopefully you find the logic straight forward and a good introduction to doing similar problems.  Although, using integer and multiplying by 10 will work and is faster, understanding for loops will likely be very helpful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need loops here:

```
y <- as.integer(x >= 5)

# [1] 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
```

Comment: I see, but is there a way to use for-loops to go through each element of x?

Comment: @STPnCHK3PLSWhy would you want to use a loop? If there is some other aspect to the problem you are trying to solve that you don't think can be addressed this way, you may want to provide some more details in your question.

Comment: Sorry, I may have been unclear in my explanation. I tried to get it out there how I thought I understood it. Thanks for your help though. I think J.Snake's code is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
y <- as.integer(x > 5)*10
```

```
# [1] 10  0  0 10  0  0  0 10  0 10  0  0
```

Your code has output as character. There is no need to do that just for printing but if you need the result as character for some other reason you can just do `as.character(y)` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it easily using ifelse statement

```
x = c(6, 1, 5, 10, 3, 0, 3, 7, 1, 6, 1, 4)

y =ifelse(x>=5,10,0)
```